# Pentaho Report Designer: How to view chinese simplified font when preview in PDF

Tags: pdf, pentaho, adobe-reader

I am designing a report in pentaho report designer that contain chinese simplified words, when i print preview, the chinese words appeared, but when I preview using PDF the chinese words won't come out. It is the problem of the adobe reader or in pentaho? because I already insatlled adobe reader X and installed a chinese font pack for adobe reader X but it still wont come out. Or is there something i should do after installing font pack.
And fyi I use Sim sun font for this.

This one is when I print preview in pentaho
[image]

This one is when I print in pentaho using PDF
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First go to your field u want to enable chinese fonts, make sure u click on it
Second, go to format on the menu bar 
Then find font and find advanced font tab
TICK the embed fonts and encoding : UTF-8
but make sure your font is allowed chinese words like Simsun or Simhei